# Error al insertar los datos SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

El error que recibo es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\TicketSystem\TICKET\process\val.php on
>   line 7

Código:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user_reg']) && isset($_POST['clave_reg']) && isset($_POST['nom_complete_reg'])){
        $nombre_reg=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('nom_complete_reg');
        $user_reg=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('user_reg');
        $clave_reg=md5(MysqlQuery::RequestPost('clave_reg'));
        $clave_reg2=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('clave_reg');
        $email_reg=MysqlQuery::RequestPost('email_reg');

        $asunto="Registro de cuenta en LinuxStore";
        $cabecera="From: LinuxStore El Salvador<*******@******.***>";
        $mensaje_mail="Hola ".$nombre_reg.", Gracias por registrarte en LinuxStore El Salvador. Los datos de cuenta son los siguientes:\nNombre Completo: ".$nombre_reg."\nNombre de usuario: ".$user_reg."\nClave: ".$clave_reg2."\nEmail: ".$email_reg."\n Página principal: http://www.linuxstore.com/index.php";


        if(MysqlQuery::Guardar("cliente", "nombre_completo, nombre_usuario, email_cliente, clave", "'$nombre_reg', '$user_reg', '$email_reg', '$clave_reg'")){

            /*----------  Enviar correo con los datos de la cuenta 
                mail($email_reg, $asunto, $mensaje_mail, $cabecera);
            ----------*/

            echo '
                <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:10px; z-index:10;"> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="text-center">REGISTRO EXITOSO</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        Cuenta creada exitosamente, ahora puedes iniciar sesión, ya eres usuario de LinuxStore.
                    </p>
                </div>
            ';
        }else{
            echo '
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:10px; z-index:10;"> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="text-center">OCURRIÓ UN ERROR</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        ERROR AL REGISTRARSE: Por favor intente nuevamente.
                    </p>
                </div>
            '; 
        }
    }
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center"><strong>Para poder registrarte debes de llenar todos los campos de este formulario</strong></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;Nombre completo</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom_complete_reg" placeholder="Nombre completo" required="" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{1,40}" title="Nombre Apellido" maxlength="40">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
              <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;Nombre de usuario</label>
              <input type="text" id="input_user" class="form-control" name="user_reg" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required="" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}" title="Ejemplo7 maximo 15 caracteres" maxlength="20">
              <div id="com_form"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><i class="fa fa-key"></i>&nbsp;Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="clave_reg" placeholder="Contraseña" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email_reg"  placeholder="Escriba su email" required="">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Crear cuenta</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center hidden-xs">
      <img src="img/linux.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
      <h2 class="text-primary">¡Gracias! Por preferirnos</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#input_user").keyup(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"./process/val.php?id="+$(this).val(),
                success:function(data){
                    $("#com_form").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sería genial si pones que error te da

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\TicketSystem\TICKET\process\val.php on line 7

Comment: añade el segmento de código donde estas usando usa función

Comment: Usualmente ese error se debe a que tu consulta `sql` retorna `false`, ya la probaste y te aseguraste de que funcione bien

Comment: En el error dice que el fallo está en val.php pero nos pasas otro fichero en dónde no aparece el error. Deberías revisar eso, porque no podemos ayudarte sin tener las cosas claras. De todas formas, como dice Edwin Aquino, el problema es 95% que la consulta que haces no funciona o el recurso sobre el que la haces no es correcto.